# Can I make "go to cart" not bring up a cart, until user hits "view cart"?

Tags: paypal, cart

I'm using paypal cart itself, not outside party's.  I have buttons working to put things into the cart.  When pressed, the cart comes up in a new tab. (I set it to _blank for new tab instead of _self.)  However, I don't want the cart to come up at all when they press "add to cart" button.  I want them to stay on the page and add everything before going to the cart.

Any way to do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal's Website Payments Shopping Cart is designed to work one way.   You add an item to the cart, the shopping cart screen is displayed, from there, you either continue shopping by returning to the web site or checkout.   This behavior is by design and there are no features or options to change it.    Depending your web browser, the shopping cart will open in the same window or a second window.  There are tricks to change how it opens but you cannot stop it from opening each time.

If you go with a 3rd party shopping cart, most have their own built in features to control the cart behavior and you only see the PayPal Screens for the final check out.   Also, note, most mini-carts are also designed to work that way.

More details, please refer solution as below link.

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/How-to-use-PayPal-Archive/Add-to-Cart-button-without-automatically-opening-the-shopping/td-p/33300

Comment: That info is on Paypals main page for carts.  i've read it and seen it around.  However their literature also says you can't specify quanitity with carts, but you can.  And that you can't specify an open ended amount gotten from the user in an input field, and you can.  So I'm looking for the person or programmer who's figured out how to do this.... like I found with the other two problems.